# SQL: Select values by column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to fetch values form a table, but the reference is the column name of the destination table instead of a key - yes, bad design.
To be honest, I have no clue where to start; could you give me some directions pelase?

Here is what I have

'Source' Table

```
ID | TargetField
---+-------------
 1 |   Field1   
 1 |   Field2   
 2 |   Field2   
 3 |   Field1
```

Rerenced Table:

```
ID | Field1 | Field2
---+--------+---------
 1 |   A    | B
 2 |   R    | C
 3 |   X    | D
```

The result would be this:

```
ID | TargetField | Value
---+-------------+-------
 1 |    Field1   |   A  
 1 |    Field2   |   B  
 2 |    Field2   |   C  
 3 |    Field1   |   X
```

As said, no idea how to get started... Am I looking at some dynamic SQL?

EDIT: The example is quite simplified, so switch/case will not work for me. I'd like to go for dynamic sql.

Comment: heh, yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that does NOT require Dynamic SQL.  That said, I suspect dynamic SQL and/or UNPIVOT would be more performant.

- Cross Apply B will convert the record to XML
- Cross Apply C will consume the B's XML and UNPIVOT the record
- Then it is a small matter to join the Source table on ID and Item

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=af253201e52c309a673736f75ebecdee)**

```
Select A.[ID]
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Id','Other-Columns','To-Exclude')
             ) C
 Join Source D on A.ID=D.ID and C.Item=D.TargetField
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Item    Value
1   Field1  A
1   Field2  B
2   Field2  C
3   Field1  X
```

Comment: A word of caution.  XML does not like column names with special characters and those that begin with numbers.

Comment: Thats amazing, but what It does, it creates one column per field I've used in the resultset. So I will have many columns with mostly null values. I'd like to have it "per row". I just edited my example to demonstrate

Comment: @Jaster The solution provided will generate the updated desired results

Comment: @Jaster See the updated dbFiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0006d5bc51d4fa85307492cf0122fa27

Comment: @Jaster Happy to help.   Just to be clear... You may have to rethink this approach on LARGE tables.   I tend to use this technique to normalize smaller result sets.  :)

Comment: What does `B` mean in `B(XMLData)` and why does the query keep working when I replace `B` by `random_word`?

Comment: @Mason B is just the alias for the CROSS APPLY.  If you have 2016+ ... the JSON version is a nudge more performant   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468392/how-to-transform-columns-to-rows-in-sql-server/72468619#72468619

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select s.id,
       (case when s.targetfield = 'field1' then r.field1
             when s.targetfield = 'field2' then r.field2
        end)
from source s join
     referenced r
     on s.id = r.id;
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but it's over simplified. Lets assume we have 30+ different columns and maybe even different tables (referenced in another field). I'm looking for some kind of join aiming at the structure.

Comment: Then you'll need a lot of `CASE` expressions @Jaster. Otherwise, yes, you'll need Dynamic SQL; but this type of SQL normally points at a design flaw.

Comment: I know it is/seems flaw design. And I assume I need dynamic sql... but I have no clue how to