# How to transform columns to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to transform columns to rows but keep the first column to repeat in every single row?

```
SELECT TOP 1 Material, Past, WK1_05_23, WK2_05_30, WK3_06_06
FROM Forecast
```

This is the result:

```
Material       Past  WK1_05_23  WK2_05_30   WK3_06_06
-----------------------------------------------------
01-298450-02    0       1           2           3
```

The expected output:

```
Material       Quantity
-----------------------
01-298450-02      0
01-298450-02      1 
01-298450-02      2
01-298450-02      3
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The foundation of your issue here is that you do not have normalized data structures. This should be two tables instead of numbered columns. The thing you looking for is called UNPIVOT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your column names I suspect the source data will expand over time

Here is a method where you can dynamically unpivot your data without actually using dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select A.[Material]
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,Value
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('Material','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
Material        Key         Value
01-298450-02    Past        0
01-298450-02    WK1_05_23   1
01-298450-02    WK2_05_30   2
01-298450-02    WK3_06_06   3
```

Comment: Thank you John, your assumption is correct and it works perfectly in my case.

Comment: @DaleK "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." ???

Comment: @DaleK Great, got it. I just did.