# What does the "B" mean in the linked answer, when the query still works however I name it?

Tags: sql, xml, cross-apply

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56825537/3037607

```
Select A.[ID]
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData) -- This B here
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Id','Other-Columns','To-Exclude')
             ) C
 Join Source D on A.ID=D.ID and C.Item=D.TargetField
```

I tried this on my own database, but I can't wrap my head around what the `B` means in `B(XMLData)`.
When I remove the `B`, I get the following error:

```
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'XMLData'.
```

But when I replace it by (for example) `helloworld(XMLData)`, the query still works...

I haven't been able to find a answer online which explains this for me.

Comment: basically it is a table alias, as you don't use it in the select, you can name it as you want, nothing would change. But when you add b.* to your select you will see what it contains